# When did Tyrion say to Jaime that it was he who committed this murder?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I can totally remember, that in response to Jaime's confession that Tysha was innocent, Tyrion said to him that he himself had killed

> Joffrey.

But I do not remember whether it was in the book or in the series, so, could anyone remind me?

Comment: This was one of my *least* favorite scenes of the show.  In the books, Jaime's confession about Tysha was one of the only times Tyrion got well and truly angry, telling Jaime that Cersei has "been f***ing Lancel and Osmund Kettleblack and Moon Boy for all I know," words that haunted Jaime forever after.  In the show, they largely glossed over Tysha and completely glossed over how much she meant to Tyrion; Jaime made no such confession, and Tyrion's last words to him were tame. I don't think Tyrion said anything about Joffrey in the show, but the bit about Tysha was definitely only in the books

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet: Tyrion speaking about Joffrey might have been considered "more of the same" when he already stated that he would have wanted to kill Joffrey at his own trial. Also, it seems a bit of an overstatement to say that the show "completely glossed over how much she meant to Tyrion". Although we only see Tyrion recount the events, it's clear how much these events have defined his relationship with Tywin. The Tysha story (in the show) seems to mostly be used to explain the Tywin-Tyrion relationship. Jaime's storyline has been mostly detached from Tyrion's (except for the jailbreak)

Comment: Well I disagree that I overstated the difference-- in the show he told the story once and the whole event is never mentioned again, whereas in the books he thinks about her constantly and talks about her to multiple people (and looking for her is a big part of his motivations later on)-- but regardless, the point I was making was that the show changed Tyrion's story in a big way, and I didn't like it lol.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't know about the series, but in the books, he does, right after Jaime admits that Tyrion's traumatic experience with Tysha was a setup and a betrayal:

> Jaime handed him the ring of keys.  "I gave you the truth.  You owe me
>   the same.  Did you do it?  Did you kill him?"
>
> [Tyrion asks if he really wants to know, describes how bad Joffrey
>   was]
>
> "You have not answered my question."
>
> "You poor stupid blind crippled fool.  Must I spell every little thing
>   out for you?  Very well.  Cersei [is bad] and [is promiscuous].  And I
>   am the monster they say I am.  Yes, I killed your vile son."  He made
>   himself grin.  It must have been a hideous sight to see, there in the
>   torchlit gloom.

For the record, we know from internal POV and from details gleaned from other characters that Tyrion was innocent of that crime.  And everything he said about Cersei is true.  The best motive we can infer is that Tyrion is sick of his family, betrayed by the one member of it that he trusted, and lashing out with truth and lie together to drive a wedge between them.

Comment: It's worth noting, I think, that Tyrion knows for a fact that it isn't true even as he says the words.  He says it just to get back at Jaime for what happened to Tysha.

Comment: +1 worth mentioning the truth Jaime told to Tyrion and what Pluto said

Comment: Yeah, I know, that Tyrion was innocent. But with Ollena's confession in third episode, it would mean for Jaime so much more! He would finally know, that what Tyrion had  said to him was a lie and would probably forgive him, and be repelled by Cersei a little bit more

Comment: @OlgaGekkel Except that Olenna confessed to Jaime only in show and in show, Tyrion never told Jaime that he murdered joff.

Comment: @Dulkan well, yes, but it went from a setup ("For the last 20 years, you believed I'd contrived what was an actual relationship") to a different setup ("but instead, I took something good and ruined it by tattling to our father; you trusted me and I betrayed that trust").  Before and after the confession, Tyrion is left with a betrayal by someone he trusted; having the one replaced with the other was like having the knife removed and reinserted before twisting.

Answer (score 18):

It was in the books and Gowenfawr has already added the books answer.

In the show, Tyrion never confessed it to Jaime or anyone else that he killed Joff.

From S04E06:

> Tywin: Do you wish to confess?
>
> Tyrion: Yes, Father. I'm guilty. Guilty. Is that what you want to
>   hear?
>
> Tywin: You admit you poisoned the king?
>
> Tyrion: No, of that I'm innocent.

Earlier he had confirmed to Jaime that he didn't do it in S04E04:

> Jaime: Did you do it?
>
> Tyrion: The Kingslayer brothers. You like it? I like it. You're really
>   asking if I killed your son?
>
> Jaime: Are you really asking if I'd kill my brother? How can I help
>   you?
>
> Tyrion: Well, you could set me free.

This is how Tyrion departed in S04E10:

> Tyrion: Oh, get on with it, you son of a whore.
>
> Jaime: Is that any way to speak about our mother?
>
> Tyrion: What are you doing?
>
> Jaime: What do you think I'm doing? A galley's waiting in the bay
>   bound for the Free Cities.
>
> Tyrion: Who's helping you?
>
> Jaime: Varys.
>
> Tyrion: Varys?
>
> Jaime: You have more friends than you thought. There's a locked door
>   at the top of the stairs. nock on it twice, then twice again.
>
> Tyrion: I suppose this is good-bye, then.
>
> Jaime: Farewell, little brother.
>
> Tyrion: Jaime. Thank you for my life.

They didn't mention Tysha, or Tywin's lie, or Jaime's role in the lie nor did Tyrion confess murdering Joff.

Also if someone is wondering what Truth did Jaime tell Tyrion in the books:

> "Tysha?" His stomach tightened. "What of her?"
>
> "She was no whore. I never bought her for you. That was a lie that
>   Father commanded me to tell. Tysha was . . . she was what she seemed
>   to be. A crofter's daughter, chance met on the road."
>
> Tyrion could hear the faint sound of his own breath whistling hollowly
>   through the scar of his nose. Jaime could not meet his eyes. Tysha. He
>   tried to remember what she had looked like. A girl, she was only a
>   girl, no older than Sansa. "My wife," he croaked. "She wed me."
>
> "For your gold, Father said. She was lowborn, you were a Lannister of
>   Casterly Rock. All she wanted was the gold, which made her no
>   different from a whore, so . . . so it would not be a lie, not truly,
>   and . . . he said that you required a sharp lesson. That you would
>   learn from it, and thank me later . . ."
>
> "Thank you?" Tyrion's voice was choked. "He gave her to his guards. A
>   barracks full of guards. He made me . . . watch." Aye, and more than
>   watch. I took her too . . . my wife . . .
>
> "I never knew he would do that. You must believe me."
>
> "Oh, must I?" Tyrion snarled. "Why should I believe you about
>   anything, ever? She was my wife!"
>
> “Tyrion –it...”
>
> He hit him. It was a slap, backhanded, but he put all his strength
>   into it, all his fear, all his rage, all his pain. Jaime was
>   squatting, unbalanced. The blow sent him tumbling backward to the
>   floor. “I... I suppose I earned that.”

Comment: `I think it passing odd that I am loved by one for a kindness I never did, and reviled by so many for my finest act.` - Jaime